Can't boot into Windows after dual boot installation
I was installing Ubuntu as a second OS and after the installation Windows wouldn't boot. At the start the Windows partition wouldn't mount, but after repair it would. Then Windows wouldn't start. It would only show the Lenovo logo (that I am pretty sure it is part of the Windows startup) and then it boots into Linux normally. I tried rebuilding the bcd, but it failed and I got the error device not found, but the /scanos command finds the Windows installation.
I have a problem with my Windows BCD, and not with Ubuntu or grub. As requested, this is my partition table:

and this is my Gparted.
I'm on UEFI mode(this is my /sys/firware folder), and i'm not trying to change to BIOS mode. I'm also pretty sure that windows is in legacy mode, but it is a very old computer (close to 10 years) that had Windows installed when i bought it. I've also tried using Boot Repair and Rescatux from this question, but neither of them worked. I also tried the guide from this site, when i got to this command bcdboot C:\Windows /S E: I got the error error while the copy of the startup file. Does anyone know how to resolve it? I was thinking that maybe I only need to delete and then rebuild the bcd partition. If someone knows how to do it properly I'll be really happy.
If my post isn't 100% correct, feel free to tell me or edit it. I am not good at speaking english.

Google "Windows Media Creation Tool".  Create a Rescue USB using the tool, boot from the USB to enter the Rescue Environment, and use this website to rebuild the BCD for Windows.  After doing so, take a look at rEFInd

I've tried but when I try to do the bcdboot command I get the generic error " error while te copy of the startup file" I'm translating from Italian so it might be not 100% accurate

Did you accidently format your EFI partition? Or did you try to mount the Windows Drive with Hibernation enabled?.

I have a windows installation in legacy mode. I don't know if I've mounted it with Hibernation enable, maybe i can look somewhere to wind out

Was ubuntu installed in CSM/Legacy mode?

I don't know, but i don't think so

Find another USB, or use the one you've created for Windows and instead create a GParted Live USB.  Post a screenshot in your question, so I can see your Partition Layout

Systems since 2012 are UEFI, Microsoft required UEFI with gpt partitioning. Windows 7 could be UEFI, but most were old BIOS boot with very old MBR partitioning. You need to know how Windows is installed. If system is upgrade from Windows 7, then full Ubuntu may be too much, and you need a lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie I have used Kubuntu on both old & newer systems as mid-weight flavor. In addition to above, post this: sudo parted -l in question.

This question is similar to: Convert from EFI to BIOS boot mode. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your msdos partitioned disk makes Windows a legacy install. Pre 2012 machines May be UEFI, without secure boot (like Lenovo), firmware settings determine how a media boots (prefer legacy over UEFI). Looks like your Ubuntu install was in UEFI mode (I see an esp flag), so maybe just reinstall Ubuntu in legacy mode.

I'm making a clarification here. My problem is not with ubuntu (it works just fine) but it is with windows. Even after I've switched back to legacy mode (and Ubuntu still starts) windows tries to load but then immediately crashes ( without a blue screen or nothing it just show a black screen and then it switches back to ubuntu)If

Please add clarification and requested information into your original posting (edit).  Information may be lost when in the comments.
